# Is "I shut up" proper english grammar

Tags: american-english, past-tense

So I saw that "shutted" isn't an English word, but "I shut up" doesn't sound proper.

If you were to tell someone "I shut up", talking in past tense, would that be proper?

Comment: Hi Vince. Welcome to [English Stack Exchange!](http://english.stackexchange.com) The past tense of a verb can be found in any dictionary. If you have looked in a dictionary but still have questions, please edit this question, or consider asking at [English Language Learner's Stack Exchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), which is intended to provide help with more basic English questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is correct. It probably sounds peculiar because it is the same as present tense.  You can avoid confusion regarding tense if you say, for instance:

I shut up when [somebody] [did something].

There are many English verbs (such as *cut, put, cast*, etc.) whose past tense and past participle are the same as present first-person.

Here is a list:  http://jakubmarian.com/english-verbs-that-are-the-same-in-the-present-tense-and-the-past-tense/

Answer (score 1):

shut [shut] 
v (past shut, past participle shut, present participle shut·ting, 3rd person present singular shuts)

shut up would be the past tense. 
like read is the past tense of read.

Shut up is most often used in the imperative though, which doesn't have a past tense obviously.

So I shut up sounds good

If you have a look at this link [we can find shut-upped is a word too](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=9axUTANFrAYC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=shut%20upped&source=bl&ots=fzwM62B2HI&sig=XUxUkB_kM8pd_FR_Ph1YQCzvvZA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rjc7VY6YD8SIuASbtYHAAQ&ved=0CEoQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=shut%20upped&f=false)

Comment: Your link leads to nothing.